# Sony Xperia Z1 Compact D5503 (Android 5.1.1) extremely laggy typing

Tags: keyboard

Sony Xperia Z1 Compact D5503 with Android 5.1.1 os.

I got this cheap phone ~a year and a half ago.
Works well overall, but there's one problem that I had since I bought it, the typing is very slow; it's extremely laggy, I press a key, it displays the visual animated keypress for a couple of seconds until it identifies the next keypress. Then 1 more second for another keypress. This is ridiculous. In fact I still use my iPod 2G for notes and whatnot I bought in 2009 and typing works perfectly; no lag at all.

This doesn't always happen but I cannot identify the prime cause. It mostly happens when I'm typing in notes, and sometimes on the web browser. Other times web browser might work fine, messages work fine. I tried installing 'Gboard the Google Keyboard' app, in case it'd help but no. Same thing.

I didn't mind much at first because I very rarely use it, occasionally for notes. But lately I've been using it more (you don't have much to do in the army other than get a smartphone with internet and browse the web, or read, to pass the time) and I am seriously at the brink of tossing it 100 f*in metres away. I do want to get a "dumb phone" asap actually if this is not resolved.

If you have anything to suggest that would be great.

Comment: The device has a quadcore and 2GB RAM, even if old it should be not that slow. I assume because of the Android OS and it's vulnerabilities you may have accumulated a lot of malware (ad-clicker) on your device that is stealing the performance. Or you have too many XXL_apps running in background. Have you ever considered to unlock the device and install LineageOS - eg. LineageOS 16 (-> Android 9). There are no official builds, but the unofficial one seems to be relative stable: https://forum.xda-developers.com/sony-xperia-z1-compact/development/rom-lineage-os-16-0-xperia-z1-compact-t3886233

Comment: Yes, malware might have been the case. I performed the all powerful factory reset and after testing it for a couple of weeks it seems to be fine now, fast responding, no lags. It's all good.